# How to create a MSG file with CC with PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, outlook

I try to create a msg file with powershell. I could already add the subject, and the receiver. but I can not add a CC.

This is what I have so far:

```
$obj = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application
$mail = $obj.CreateItem(0) 

$Mail.Recipients.Add("email@email.com") 

$Mail.Recipients.Type = olCC
$Mail.Recipients.Add("email2@email.com") 
$Mail.Recipients.Add("email3@email.com") 

$Mail.Subject = "Some Subject" 
$Mail.Body = "test mail with powershell"

$Mail.Attachments.Add("c:\Users\se\Desktop\Attachment.txt")
$mail.SaveAs("c:\Users\se\Desktop\test.msg")

c:\Users\se\Desktop\test.msg
```

I tried to change the Recipient object from the default ("To") to CC but this doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.recipients) you need to change the type on the recipient objects, not on the `Recipients` collection before adding the recipients.

```
$cc = $Mail.Recipients.Add("email2@email.com")
$cc.Type = 2
$cc = $Mail.Recipients.Add("email3@email.com")
$cc.Type = 2
```

Also, `olCC` is not a valid constant in PowerShell. You need to either assign the [numeric value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.olmailrecipienttype) of the constant (see above), define the constant yourself

```
$olCC = 2
# alternatively, if you want $olCC to be an actual constant:
#New-Variable -Name olCC -Value 2 -Option Constant
...
$cc = $Mail.Recipients.Add("email2@email.com")
$cc.Type = $olCC
$cc = $Mail.Recipients.Add("email3@email.com")
$cc.Type = $olCC
```

or look up the value in the Interop assembly (untested):

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook
...
$cc = $Mail.Recipients.Add("email2@email.com")
$cc.Type = [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Constants]::olCC
$cc = $Mail.Recipients.Add("email3@email.com")
$cc.Type = [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Constants]::olCC
```